# Get Requesting User's IP Address Within Apache XMLRPC environment?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, xml-rpc

I have a very basic XMLRPC Servlet Server running - literally following the defaults suggested by the Apache folks (http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/server.html).

Is there any way for me to access the requestor's IP address from within my XMLRPC functions? I'm designing a service that logs the requests it's received from different users by IP address.

For example, if I were taking the Calculator class from their example, I might do something like,

```
public int add(int a, int b){
   IPAddress user = {magic incantation};
   Log.info("Summed " + a + " and " + b + " for " + user);
   return a + b;
}
```

(obviously this is a toy example, but if I knew how to do that, I could do what I wanted to do in my program)

Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 1):

When processing a request, you have access to an instance of `HttpServletRequest`. This object provides the method [`getRemoteAddr()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29).

ALSO: In the FAQs, you will find [this snippet](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/faq.html#client_ip) to get and store the IP as a `ThreadLocal` so you can access it henceforth (maybe this is more than what you want).

A reproduction of the snippet is:

```
public static class ClientInfoServlet extends XmlRpcServlet {
    private static ThreadLocal clientIpAddress = new ThreadLocal();

    public static String getClientIpAddress() {
        return (String) clientIpAddress.get();
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest pRequest, HttpServletResponse pResponse)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        clientIpAddress.set(pRequest.getRemoteAddr());
        super.doPost(pRequest, pResponse);
    }
}
```